# Show form only after DocumentCompleted event gets finished

Tags: c#, winforms

I am having a form `form1` from which I am calling another form `form2`. 
There is a Web Browser Control in form2.
What happens is at once form2 gets shown and then after document completed event of web browser, form2 gets resized.

```
void wbBrowser_DocumentCompleted(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    //Set the height/width of form2, so web page gets visible completely without scroll bars.
    this.Height = wbBrowser.Document.Body.ScrollRectangle.Height;
    this.Width = wbBrowser.Document.Body.ScrollRectangle.Width;
}
```

This looks non professional as the same form gets loaded twice. What I want is to show the form2 only after `DocumentCompleted` event of web browser control gets completed.

Comment: And the form does not get loaded twice, it resizes... so you won't be able to do what you ask because the control has to be loaded before it can even fire an event. If the control is loaded its parent is too.

Comment: First you should define expected behavior. Then you can simply achieve it. If you need help, then define expected behavior and notify me.